# ISP caching certain browsers?

Tags: caching, browser

When I updated my website on my tower pc, Firefox and chrome do not update the result they remain on the domain providers Parked webpage. However, Opera does update an goes to my server and all is working well. But only with Opera.

So I get off my tower pc as I thought it was a cache issue on my machine.

I go on a mobile internet device using the same virgin superhub router but this time via wi-fi, and again firefox and chrome do not show the updated website result but Opera does.

so the same result on both tower and mobile. Indicating perhaps this is not a cache issue on my browsers.

It's like my ISP or domain provider is caching firefox and chrome, but Opera is bypassing this cache and going to my server as it should?

please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely:

Your router has cached the DNS settings of the holding page, so any request going out from your LAN will get directed to the old IP address.

Opera could be configured to use a proxy which has been a feature of the mobile apps for a long time and was [added to desktop Opera](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2016/09/28/opera-browser-starts-running-traffic-through-its-own-vpn/) a couple of years ago. This would bypass your local DNS server.

When the TTL of the old DNS expires, you could get the new site.

Comment: Thank you very much .  that makes sense.  i shall see if i can clear the cache? otherwise i'll have to wait..i wonder how long? ...hopefully not a year. lol  : p

Answer (score 0):

To those on virgin media super hub. it finally worked. the DNS settings cache cleared.

I believe it took approx 48 hrs ( hard to tell exactly)

so if you buy a domain you have been viewing(viewed its parked page),you may be able to use Opera browser sooner as it does not use the routers dns cache if set up as a proxy. And also you can use a proxy website to view your domain online.  You may be able to reset your router to clear the cache? I did not want to lose my settings, so I waited.  It just takes some time on firefox chrome and perhaps a few other browsers (on the router you have recently viewed the domain) as these browsers rely on the dns cache on the router.
From what I gather.peace :)